# best_in_place when using :display_with shows text AND nil value. Only allows editing of nil value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

I have the following code:

```
<%= best_in_place_if can?(:update, risk), risk, :effect, :display_with => :simple_format, :path => assessment_risk_path(assessment,risk), type: :textarea, html_attrs: { "class" => "input-block-level" }, :nil => "Click to add a effect..." %>
```

What I get on screen is

> Click to add a effect...
>
> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
>   accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam,
>
> eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae
>   vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
>
> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut
>   fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem
>   sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor
>   sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
>   tempora inci

The attribute's text is correctly formatted, but:

1. Why is it showing both the nil text AND the attribute's actual text?
2. I can only click and edit the "Click to add a effect..." text, not the actual attribute's text

Any ideas?

Comment: Works fine for me. May be you're using not originally best_in_place gem with some code modification.

Comment: I've got ```gem 'best_in_place'``` in my gemfile, what more do I need?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else who might be experiencing the same issue, try removing any html tags that are wrapping around your best-in-place tag.

I had the same issue this morning with the following code:

```
<p> <%= best_in_place profile, :description, :type => :textarea, :display_with => :simple_format, :classes => 'profile-edit-field', :nil => 'Click to add a product description', :html_attrs => {:cols => '100'} %></p>
```

Removing the `<p></p>` tags fixed the issue.